Diffusion from a rod with constant concentration
Suppose I have an infinite rod that is suddenly brought into a medium where some substance  starts to diffuse radially outwards from the rod. During this, the concentration in the rod is kept constant.
I have only found analogous solutions for the case when instead of a rod we have an infinite plate. In that case the solution would be
$\frac{C_P-C_x}{C_P-C_o}=\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{D t}}\right)$ where $C_P$ is the concentration in the plate and $C_0$ is that of the medium initially, x is the distance from the plate.
How could I adapt this for the cylindrical case where $\frac{\partial C_r}{\partial t}=\frac{D}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial C_r}{\partial r}\right)$ needs to hold instead of $\frac{\partial C_x}{\partial t}=D \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2}$?

You've already adapted it by writing the Laplacian for the axisymmetric case; now you need to solve this equation. If you make the variable substitution $u(r,t)=\frac{C(r,t)-C_0}{C_\mathrm{rod}-C_0}$, where $C_\mathrm{rod}$ is the rod concentration, then the equation becomes $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{D}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)$ in the medium with simple boundary and initial conditions $u(R,t)=1$ and $u(r,0)=0$.

There are several discussions on this solution on the Math Stack Exchange site (example); instead of the error function, Bessel functions arise.

The solution is also discussed in §13.5 ("The region bounded internally by the circular cylinder") of Carslaw & Jaeger.
